# React: Loading gapi and currentUser on page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set up a redirect when a page loads if the user is or is not signed in.

My HTML file where I initialize gapi:

```
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=start" async defer></script>
        <script>
            function start() {
                console.log('script running')
                gapi.load('auth2', function() {
                    auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                        client_id: '817677528939-dss5sreclldv1inb26tb3tueac98d24r.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                        scope: 'profile email'
                    });
                });
            }
        </script>
```

User signs in on Login.js

```
/* global gapi */

import React from 'react';

import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import $ from 'jquery'


class Login extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleSignIn = this.handleSignIn.bind(this)
        this.signInCallback = this.signInCallback.bind(this)
    }

    handleSignIn() {
        console.log(gapi.auth2)
        var x = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().grantOfflineAccess()
        console.log(x)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <AppBar className='appBar' title="Pliny" showMenuIconButton={false} zDepth={2} />
                <button  id="signinButton" onClick={this.handleSignIn} >Sign in with Google</button>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

class SignIn2 extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.updateRedirect = this.updateRedirect.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            redirect: false,
            loaded: false
        }
    }

    updateRedirect() {
        this.setState({
            redirect: true
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        gapi.load('auth2', () => {
            gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '817677528939-dss5sreclldv1inb26tb3tueac98d24r'
            }).then((auth2) => {
                console.log( "signed in: " + auth2.isSignedIn.get())
                this.setState({
                    redirect: auth2.isSignedIn.get(),
                    loaded: true
                }, () => {console.log('this finished')})
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.loaded){
            console.log(this.state.loaded)
            return null
        }

        console.log(this.state.loaded)
        return (
            this.state.redirect ?
            <Redirect to='/options' /> : <Login updateRedirect = {this.updateRedirect} />
        )
    }    
}

export default SignIn2
```

I have a redirect setup to handle the signing in (and no problems here).

However, I am having issues now on the `/options` page.

Options.js

```
    componentDidMount() {    
        gapi.load('auth2', () => {
            var googleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
            console.log(googleAuth)
        })
```

When the page initially redirects, `googleAuth` prints out with a value

`jF {zd: {…}, aea: "single_host_origin", Ofa: true, d2: true, Z1: undefined, …}`

However, when I refresh the page, it now prints out as `null`.

Why?

Secondly, I have a button that prints out the gapi info:

```
checkUserData() {
    var googleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
    console.log( "signed in: " + googleAuth.isSignedIn.get())
    var user = googleAuth.currentUser.get()
    console.log(user)
}
```

When I press the button that runs `checkUserData()`, it prints out with the user data that I was expected.

So why does `componentDidMount` print out `null` when I refresh the page? I am still logged in and can access the user data from a button.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding a lot of JavaScript logic to your `index.html` file and it may be confusing you because well you are having to go back and forth between `index.html` and your `Options.js` and `Login.js`.

Consider the following, for your `index.html`, only put this in there:

`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>`

Done, close that file, never reference it again.

Next, for your JS file or files, you want something that looks like this:

```
import React from "react";

class someClassComponentYouDecideOn extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
      window.gapi.client.init({
        clientId:
          "1234567890-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        scope: "email"
      });
    });
  }
```

Now, make sure the above works for you by practicing signing in and out in the Chrome console.

`gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()` in the console will give you the `auth` object properties, you will see `signIn` and `signOut` as two of the many properties it has and you can practice via:

`gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()` and `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut()`.

Of course to see the results on your browser you will probably need to create a helper function with an if conditional that you can render to your browser like so:

```
renderAuthButton() {
    if (this.state.isSignedIn === null) {
      return <div>I dont know if I am signed in</div>;
    } else if (this.state.isSignedIn) {
      return <div>I am signed in!</div>;
    } else {
      return <div>I am not signed in</div>;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderAuthButton()}</div>;
  }
}
```

That `isSignedIn` is not made up, it's also one of the properties of the `auth` object in the `gapi` library.

Once you have verified this, then you can deal with the Promise like so:

```
import React from "react";

class someClassComponentYouDecideOn extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
      window.gapi.client.init({
        clientId:
          "1234567890-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        scope: "email"
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        this.setState({ isSignedIn: this.auth.isSignedIn.get() });
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use my package: [gapi-script](https://github.com/partnerhero/gapi-script), this package provides the gapi function right way, so you don't have to wait the script load.

Also check out this example that does exactly what you're trying to do, [example that checks if user is logged in or not, with gapi-script](https://github.com/LucasAndrad/gapi-script-live-example)

[Checking user google session](https://github.com/LucasAndrad/gapi-script-live-example/blob/master/src/components/GoogleLogin.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { gapi, loadAuth2 } from 'gapi-script'

import UserCard from './UserCard';
import './GoogleLogin.css';

class GoogleLogin extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: null
        }
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        let auth2 = await loadAuth2(process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID, '')
        if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
            this.updateUser(auth2.currentUser.get())
        } else {
            this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'), auth2);
        }
    }
    async componentDidUpdate() {
        if(!this.state.user) {
            let auth2 = await loadAuth2(process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID, '')
            this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'), auth2);
        }
    }
    updateUser(currentUser) {
        let name = currentUser.getBasicProfile().getName()
        let profileImg = currentUser.getBasicProfile().getImageUrl()
        this.setState({
            user: {
                name: name,
                profileImg: profileImg
            }
        })
    }
    attachSignin(element, auth2) {
        auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
            (googleUser) => {
                this.updateUser(googleUser);
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
            });
    }
    signOut = () => {
        let auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(() => {
            this.setState({ user: null })
            console.log('User signed out.');
        });
    }
    render() {
        if(this.state.user) {
            return (
                <div className="container">
                    <UserCard user={this.state.user} />
                    <div id="" className="btn logout" onClick={this.signOut}>
                        Logout
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div className="container">
                    <div id="customBtn" className="btn login">
                        Login
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default GoogleLogin;
```

Answer (score 0):

`getAuthInstance` requires `init` to be called before being used. My assumption is that the Google API is storing your auth session in Local Storage (you check this in the browser) which is why you're able to use your `checkUserData()` method. But on page refresh the init function isn't being called, thus the auth instance is null.

Comment: but I get an error when I call init() `"gapi.auth2 has been initialized with different options. Consider calling gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() instead of gapi.auth2.init()."`

Comment: I call init() in my HTML file

Comment: Sounds to me like you don't need to use `gapi.load` in your options file since auth2 is already loaded at this point. Try getting the authInstance inside componentDidMount without trying to load again

Comment: yea, I got a separate error when I did that. the `start()` script was loading AFTER the react component so it wasn't loading properly

Comment: Is this sourced on GitHub at all? CodePen?

Comment: Cloning and looking